# How to sort an array by multiple weights?

Tags: sorting

For example: I have an array of Humans:

```
Human{
private int eyeColor;
private int hairColor;
private int height;
}
```

I would like to sort the array by multiple weights:

Eye colors is the most valuable (higher the better)
after wards - height, and finally hair color

etc.

Assuming all ints are ranged 0-10
I thought about creating a "rank" field for Human entity:
than multiply it by the following logic:

```
rank+= 10000 * eyeColor;
rank+= 1000 * height;
rank+= 100 * hairColor;
```

Afterwards just sort by rank.

I feel like this is a primitive way to sort by weights (if its even right).
Are there any more elegant ways for this?

Comment: You should *add* your rank values, not multiply them.

Comment: oops that's what i actually meant. thanks

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: "pseueava"  - pseudo code + java :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my answer was focused too heavy on implementation details. Your question is if there are more elegant ways for this? And I'm saying no. You basically have to map an object with 3 integers to one single integer which you can compare later on.

If there will be much more attributes in your class which you have to include in the comparison in the future I'm suggesting you could make some more generic version of your code where each attribute consists of a attribute and a corresponding weight. In that way you can create a more generic form of the compareTo-method. But don't optimize prematurely.

I would recommend implementing the [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface like this:

```
public Human(int eyeColor, int hairColor, int height) {
    this.eyeColor = eyeColor;
    this.hairColor = hairColor;
    this.height = height;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Human> humans = new ArrayList<Human>();
    humans.add(new Human(20, 10, 5));
    humans.add(new Human(50, 50, 2));

    Collections.sort(humans);
    for(Human human : humans) {
        System.out.println(human);
    }
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Human o) {

    int thisRank = 10000 * eyeColor;
    thisRank += 1000 * height;
    thisRank += 100 * hairColor;

    int otherRank = 10000 * o.eyeColor;
    otherRank += 1000 * o.height;
    otherRank += 100 * o.hairColor;

    return thisRank - otherRank;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer would be no. When it comes to ranking with multiple attributes/criteria, one of the simplest formulas you can use is:

rank = (weight1 * attribute1) + (weight2 * attribute2) + ... + (weightN * attributeN)

which is pretty much what you have already.

The values of the weights are completely up to you to decide, but as you know they can have just as much affect on the rank as the attributes themselves. So coming up with a good heuristic (i.e. the set of values for the weights) is very important for a ranking system. Unfortunately, more often than not, this involves trial and error (very painful and time consuming).

Just fyi, you can have the machine automate this process and self adjust the weights using a feedback loop. You will need to research a bit about *machine learning*.